# Anime where a girl kills her friend over and over because she was going to a different school

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember the anime was about a girl who would kill her best friend over and over because she was going to a different school.

The girl going to the different school had blue hair i believe, and she was very smart. The friend that was the killer friend had orange hair; I believe wanted to kill the blue haired(?) friend because she didn't want her to go to another school.

I saw it on  YouTube video but now I can't find it. I did look it up but, on an old phone that got destroyed. I'm pretty sure it was a mundane school, just a regular school. I don't know if it was from an anime watching website like crunchyroll, but it probably was. I am almost positive the genre was was horror thriller, gore, or something on the line of that

Comment: Do you remember either girl's hair color? Was this a Japanese school? A magic one? A mundane one? How does she get to kill her friend over and over? Time loop? Resurrection? Time Travel?

Comment: Consider having a look at this checklist about [_"how to ask a good (anime/manga) Story-ID question"_](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/40711) to help you remember other important details, and [edit] them in the question.

Comment: This must be a definition of "friend" I'm unaware of.

Comment: Thank you Ifurini I will try

Comment: What happens when the girl is killed? Does time reset (for everyone)? Is she just an immortal? Something else? Is the victim even aware she's being killed repeatedly? Do you remember when you saw this?

Comment: *Higurashi* springs to mind - I know it has a girl with blue hair, a lot of violence and gore, and some sort of time-loop scenario, but I'm not sure whether it has the exact scenario described in the question. I'll have to check when I have time.

Comment: F1Krazy That's the one thank you so much

Comment: @Potato I've posted it as an answer, which you should now be able to accept to mark your issue as having been resolved.

Answer (score 7):

OP has confirmed in the comments that this is *Higurashi no Naku Koro Ni*. The blue-haired girl would be Rika Furude (second-from-left), and the orange-haired girl would be Rena Ryuuguu (center).

[image]

I know that *Higurashi* has a considerable amount of gore, and some sort of time-loop element, but I don't actually know enough about it to elaborate on how it matches the rest of the question.

Comment: One thing that might have been misremembered as "wanted to kill the blue haired(?) friend because she didn't want her to go to another school": part of the curse of Hinamizawa is that it triggers if the people live away from their village for too long. In fact Rena had recently moved back to the village because she'd interpreted certain tragic events as punishment for not living in the village, which is why she cares about people following the rules.

No-one ever actually gets threatened with being murdered for leaving the village. But all the ingredients are there.